# How to do a mongo restore with Atlas URI

Tags: mongorestore, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to do a `mongorestore` of a few collections . I am trying to use the Atlas URI to do this and it throws an error saying that

```
positional arguments not allowed: [mongodb+srv://hostname.mongodb.net]
```

When I try to connect with a `mongo` client it works fine. However not the `mongorestore` or mongo import.
In short

```
mongorestore  -d dbname --username foo --password bar "mongodb+srv://hostname.mongodb.net" /folderwithbsons/
```

doesn't work while the below works

```
mongo  -d dbname --username foo --password bar "mongodb+srv://hostname.mongodb.net"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with the `mongorestore` version you use. The [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--uri) says:

> Starting with version 100.0 of `mongorestore`, the connection string may alternatively be provided as a positional parameter

Run `mongorestore --version`; if it shows something less than 100.0, you'll have to use the `--uri` option to specify destination.

Comment: Thanks. I shoudl have used --uri username@password:URI.